# Why does GTmetrix give me the "serve images that are appropriately sized" error?

Tags: images, page-speed, image-size, gtmetrix

I've run a GTmetrix test on my website.

I get one issue in its audit report at https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.datanumen.com/3FtNGzq8/

[image: audit report]

I check the image with Chrome DevTools, as below:

[image: chrome devtools]

Since the test is for Desktop, the image size is 649 x 508 and it is served as 649 x 508.

Also I found that there is a `srcset` tag in the code for the different resolutions, which is also recommended in https://gtmetrix.com/blog/how-to-properly-size-images/. So I cannot find the problem with the image, why does GTmetrix report it as an issue?

Comment: I think it's better if you share the report URL

Comment: Is saving 4KB _really_ worth the effort?

Comment: Use a WebP instead and cut the file size at least third. Then tell GTmetrix to take a hike!

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur, Thank you. I have added the report URL https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.datanumen.com/3FtNGzq8/ in the op.

Answer (score 4):

GTmetrics is probably trying to tell you that you can further compress/optimize your image. By running it through a tool such as TinyPNG, or OptiPNG as recommended by [the GTmetrix page on optimizing images](https://gtmetrix.com/optimize-images.html), you can further reduce the image's size without much perceptual loss.

4.4KB is a negligible amount of potential savings, though. It probably makes sense to ignore it unless you have many images like this on the same page.